# Rails NoMethodError (undefined method `humanize' for nil:NilClass) in mail to:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have such job in my Rails app:

```
class NewAnswerNotifyJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(answer)
    Services::NewAnswerNotify.new.send_notify(answer)
  end
end
```

`Services::NewAnswerNotify`:

```
class Services::NewAnswerNotify
  def send_notify(answer)
    NewAnswerNotifyMailer.new.notify(answer)
  end
end
```

`NewAnswerNotifyMailer`:

```
class NewAnswerNotifyMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def notify(answer)
    @answer   = answer
    @question = answer.question
    @author   = answer.question.author

    mail to: @author.email
  end
end
```

When I try in Rails console (I faced with this problem on a dev server, then have replayed this behavior in console) to run `Services::NewAnswerNotify#send_notify` with an `answer` I got such error:

```
2.6.0 :023 > answer = Answer.first
  Answer Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "answers".* FROM "answers" ORDER BY "answers"."best_solution" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Answer id: 76, body: "answer body", question_id: 2, created_at: "2019-05-01 18:43:16", updated_at: "2019-05-28 15:38:16", author_id: 1, best_solution: true> 
2.6.0 :024 > Services::NewAnswerNotify.new.send_notify(answer)
  Question Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):24
        2: from app/services/new_answer_notify.rb:3:in `send_notify'
        1: from app/mailers/new_answer_notify_mailer.rb:8:in `notify'
NoMethodError (undefined method `humanize' for nil:NilClass)
2.6.0 :025 >
```

So, the error occurs in `mail to: @author.email` line in `NewAnswerNotifyMailer`, but when but itself mailer works as planned:

```
2.6.0 :025 > answer = Answer.first
  Answer Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "answers".* FROM "answers" ORDER BY "answers"."best_solution" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Answer id: 76, body: "for flexbox grid columns also means you can set th...", question_id: 2, created_at: "2019-05-01 18:43:16", updated_at: "2019-05-28 15:38:16", author_id: 1, best_solution: true> 
2.6.0 :026 > NewAnswerNotifyMailer.notify(answer)
  Question Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[i18n-debug] en.new_answer_notify_mailer.notify.subject => nil
  Rendering new_answer_notify_mailer/notify.html.slim within layouts/mailer
  Rendered new_answer_notify_mailer/notify.html.slim within layouts/mailer (4.7ms)
  Rendering new_answer_notify_mailer/notify.text.slim within layouts/mailer
  Rendered new_answer_notify_mailer/notify.text.slim within layouts/mailer (3.5ms)
NewAnswerNotifyMailer#notify: processed outbound mail in 100.5ms
 => #<Mail::Message:70164808395160, Multipart: true, Headers: <From: from@example.com>, <To: codcore@gmail.com>, <Subject: Notify>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_5d0cac2d80291_b85a3fd081039fd052340"; charset=UTF-8>>
```

I can't realize where problem is, why I get `Nil` at the `Services::NewAnswerNotify`.

Comment: you need to check your data in tables. most probably you do not have matching data to satisfy your relationships for answer.question.author

Comment: @SudiptaMondal, no all relationships work correctly. All work as supposed when I pass answer right to the mailer, but when I pass answer to the service, some value becames `Nil` inside the mailer.

Comment: In which method or function did you use `humanize`? Post the code where `humanize` is called. Seems its returning `nil` and you cant call `humanize` on `nil` object.

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi, the problem is that I don't use `humanize` method nowhere. It seems that `mail` calls it and some value called on it has `Nil` value.

Comment: Well, you need to post all other code, else we will be shooting in the dark. I suggest you debug it with `binding.pry`, you surely will see what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several suggestions:

- You should use ActionMailer class methods directly instead of instantiating a new mailer with `new`. This is probably the source of the bug
- Since your `NewAnswerNotify` is nested under `Services`, it would also make it less ambiguous to use the root namespace `::NewAnswerNotifyMailer` (some people may disagree with me on this one, but I've had so many root namespace bugs in the past that I tend to systematically use the `::` prefix now)
- Beware of class loading that works differently for `class Services::NewAnswerNotify` and `module Services class NewAnswerNotification` (lots of existing questions on this topic)

```rb
module Services
  class NewAnswerNotify
    def send_notify(answer)
      ::NewAnswerNotifyMailer.notify(answer).deliver_now # instead of .new.notify
    end
  end
end
```

Also some side comments regarding the variables and the english

I would rather use

- `Services::NewAnswerNotification`
- `NewAnswerNotificationMailer`
- `def send_notification(answer)` or `def notify(answer)`

And maybe one last piece of advice from experience after maintaining a code base in the long run: to be more explicit regarding who you are notifying of what `def notify_question_author_of_new_answer` because later you might have a `notify_question_subscribers_of_new_answer` or someone else who might need to be notified (it totally depends on your business model of course, feel free to ignore this remark)